# How to skip specific column while reading from text file in C++?

Tags: c++, string, file-io, format

I have a text file with three columns. I want to read only the first and the third. The second column is formed by a name or date.

> Input file                    |    Data read
>
> 7.1 2000-01-01 3.4 |    7.1 3.4
>
> 1.2 2000-01-02 2.5    |    1.2 2.5

or

> 5.5 Unknown 3.9       |    5.5 3.9
>
> 1.1 Unknown 2.4       |    1.1 2.4

Could someone give me a hint how to do this in C++?

Thanks!

Comment: LihO, Thanks for your help. 
However when I have a file with several columns how do I read them all. But always jumping the second column.

Answer (score 1):

*"Could someone give me a hint how to do this in C++?"*

Sure thing:

1. go through your file line by line using `std::getline`, reading every line into `std::string line;`
2. construct a temporary `std::istringstream` object for every line
3. Use `>>` operator on this stream to fill a variable of type `double` (1st column)
4. Use `>>` again to read 2nd column into `std::string` that you won't actually use
5. Use `>>` to read another `double` (3rd column)

i.e. something like:

```
std::ifstream file;
...
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    if (line.empty()) continue;     // skips empty lines
    std::istringstream is(line);    // construct temporary istringstream
    double col1, col3;
    std::string col2;
    if (is >> col1 >> col2 >> col3) {
        std::cout << "column 1: " << col1 << " column 3: " << col3 << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "This line didn't meet the expected format." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone give me a **hint** how to do this in C + +?

Just use [`std::basic_istream::operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) to put the skipped data to a dummy variable, or use [`std::basic_istream::ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to skip input until the next field delimiter you specify.

Best way to solve it should be reading line by line (see [`std::string::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)) using a `std::ifstream`, and then parse (and skip columns as mentioned above) each line separately, using `std::istringstream` in a loop over all lines in the input file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved as follows:

```
int main()
{   
ifstream file("lixo2.txt");
string line; int nl=0; int nc = 0; double temp=0;

vector<vector<double> > matrix;

while (getline(file, line))
{
size_t found = line.find("Unknown");
line.erase (found, 7);
istringstream is(line);

vector<double> myvector;

while(is >> temp)
{
    myvector.push_back(temp);
    nc = nc+1;
}
matrix.push_back(myvector);

 nl =nl+1;
}

return 0;
}
```

Thanks to everyone!!